# Intermittent Error: Failed to send request to /services/Soap/u/37.0

Tags: data-loader

I'm trying to data load tens of thousands of records and intermittently getting this error:

> Failed to send request to https://instance.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0

It sounds like this issue is supposed to be related to proxies, but **I don't have any proxy settings configured. I make sure to log out of VPN before doing any data loads.**

It kind of feels like singing out *42000 bottles of beer on the wall...* I'm just grateful it's easy to trim CSV rows with Python. Any ideas besides proxy settings for why I might get this error?

Comment: When you logged into the Data loader did you do login.salesforce.com or instance.salesforce.com?

Comment: I thought I was using `test.salesforce.com` for my sandbox, but I guess I am using `instance` after all.

Comment: The internet suggests that switching to one or the other depending on what's not working solves the issue. It is also Wednesday night which might still be hotfix night that Salesforce is running updates and things could be down.

Comment: Only with such an off-and-on issue as this could "it's Wednesday" be a possible confounding factor. Haha. I've run into this on other days though. I got through the last 12k without any errors after switching to `test.salesforce.com`, so 50/50 that fixed it?